# Load menu items from one menu in other menu

Tags: 8, hooks, navigation

I want to load the menu items from the main menu in a other menu. I've read a dozen examples but I can't get it to render the items at all.

Here's my code from `my_theme.theme`

```
function my_theme_menu__secondary(&$menu, &$menu_name, &$suggestions) {
  $menu_name = 'main';
  $menu_tree = \Drupal::menuTree();
  $parameters = new \Drupal\Core\Menu\MenuTreeParameters();
  $parameters->onlyEnabledLinks();
//  $parameters->setMinDepth(2)();
//  $parameters->setMaxDepth(2)();

  $tree = $menu_tree->load($menu_name, $parameters);
  $manipulators = array(
    array('callable' => 'menu.default_tree_manipulators:checkAccess'),
    array('callable' => 'menu.default_tree_manipulators:generateIndexAndSort'),
  );

  $tree = $menu_tree->transform($tree, $manipulators);

  $list = [];

  foreach ($tree as $item) {
    $title = $item->link->getTitle();
    $url = $item->link->getUrlObject();
    $list[] = Drupal\Core\Link::fromTextAndUrl($title, $url);
  }

  return $list;
}
```

Heres my `menu--secondary.html.twig`

```
{% import _self as menus %}

{{ menus.menu_links(items, attributes, 0) }}

{% macro menu_links(items, attributes, menu_level) %}
  {% import _self as menus %}
  {% if list %}
    {% for item in list %}
      {%
        set item_classes = [
          'expanded',
          'dropdown',
          item.in_active_trail ? 'active',
        ]
      %}
      {% if menu_level == 0  %}
        <li{{ item.attributes.addClass(item_classes) }}>
        <a href="{{ item.url }}">{{ item.title }}</a>
        </li>
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}
{% endmacro %}
```

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Hey hey, why don't you simply use a menu block? Or https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_block? You can simply place a menu multiple times on your page with just core blocks.

Comment: Because I need the menu to be displayed twice, once with menu items that are expanded to show the childs as a dropdown and once just the child when the user is in the activeTrail. Would I try to alter menu_main with a hook, it would alter both because they're one block. I've just created a block in my module to load the menu_main and now I can alter the block to my liking without affecting the menu_main ^^

Comment: That's important info. And https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_block just does what you need as it offers you menu configuration per block.

Answer (score 0):

you can add new module [twig tweak](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak), after rendering blocks menu with Twig Tweak on template.